# Is there a way to pass an array to an external REXX program?

Tags: mainframe, zos, rexx

**What I have tried:**

Program A:

```
call PROGRAMB ARRAY val1 val2
```

PROGRAM B:

```
PARSE arg ARRAY val1 val2 
/* test to see if ARRAY is passed successfully */
/* len1 equals the length of ARRAY */
interpret "len1 = "ARRAY".0"
say 'len1: ' len1 
DO i=0 TO len1
    say 'current line: '
    interpret "say "ARRAY".i"
END;
```

**Expected Results:**

1. len1 would be equivalent to the length of the array. For example if ARRAY = [1,2,3], len would be equal to 3.
2. Each member of the array should be printed.

**Actual Results:**

1. len1 is equivalent to "JOBCARD.0" not the actual length.
2. The program fails on the for loop due to a IRX0041I (Bad arithmetic conversion) and doesn't print out the members/

**Solutions I have tried:**

https://www.bde-gmbh.de/tipps-tricks/zos-rexx/how-to-pass-stems-as-procedure-arguments-in-rexx/

But this method only works for passing arrays to functions within the same program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass a stem (array) to an external Rexx EXEC.  Look into using NEWSTACK, PUSH, QUEUE, QUEUED(), PULL, DELSTACK.  These are all documented in the keyword instructions, built-in functions, and TSO/E external functions sections of the [TSO/E Rexx Reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=tsoe-zos-rexx-reference)